# Classical Information Theory vs. Quantum Information Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, information

I am quite familiar with the basic concepts of information theory (sources, alphabets, simbols, strings, information, Shannon's entropy, noisy channels, Shannon's theorems, etc.). I always thought of information theory as a general *meta-theory*, applicable to a wide range of subjects and completely independent of any specific context of application. *However* I have came to understand that nowadays we like to split information theory in two separate branches:

- Classical information theory (CIT)
- Quantum information theory (QIT)

And I suspect that we like to do this because these two are quite different from one another, *for example* in CIT we use [Shannon's entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) but in QIT we use [Von Neumann's entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy); so I get that CIT and QIT are distinct in a meaningful way, however I have difficulties pin pointing the main differences between them and what are the physical quantum effects that create these differences. I would like a summary of all the most relevant point of disagreement between the two theories.

So my question is: *What are the **main** differences between CIT and QIT? And which quantum effects are responsable for these differences?*

---

> This question is a *crosspost* with [Quantum Computing SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/). [Here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27242/classical-information-theory-vs-quantum-information-theory) is the link to the other post.

Comment: You can also crosspost to [Quantum computing SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Mauricio I am a little embarrassed to admit this: but I never crossposted before.. How should I do it?

Comment: As far as I know there is no easy way. You can copy and paste it there. Then add a link in this post that leads to the post in QCSE and add a link in the post in QCSE that links to this post.

Answer (score 1):

The Classical interpretation of the reality is certain, in the sense that it assumes that if we know everything about the state of the system, given the initial state of the system, and the interactions it has with other parts of the world, we can finde the final state of it without any uncertainty. Or to put it simply, The uncertainty in classical view of the world comes from our ignorance.

This is not the case for quantum interpretation. In quantum systems given an initial state and calculating all the interactions, we're still not able to predict the outcome of our experiment. The uncertainty in quantum view of the world comes from our ignorance and the quantum behavior of the nature.

As an example consider a bit, in classical information theory a bit is either 1 or 0. so in the most general case for a bit we have $P_1$ probability of it being 1 and $P_0$ probability of being 0. where $P_0+P_1 =1$. This is different for a qubit (short for quantum bit). For the qubit the state is a "vector" in it's Hilbert space, the Hilbert space of a qubit is two dimensional, which means that any state (vector) in the space can be written as a linear combination of it's eigen vector (the eigen vectors can be seen in eigen value theories but consider just two orthogonal vectors that can map the space completely). So for a qubit the most general case would be:

$$
\vert \text{qubit}\rangle = \alpha \vert 1 \rangle + \beta \vert0 \rangle
$$

where $\alpha^2 +\beta^2 = 1$. This is called the superposition of qubit. Note that it's not 1 or 0 and it's not 1 and 0. It is a completely different state, which can be shown as the two eigen state of the system. Now to measure this we have to use the Born rule, first we calculate the density matrix of this system which is:

$$
\rho = \vert\text{qubit}\rangle\langle\text{qubit}\vert
$$
Then by born rule the probability of finding 0 or 1 would be:
$$
\text{Tr}[\rho \vert0\rangle\langle0\vert] = \beta^2
\text{Tr}[\rho \vert1\rangle\langle1\vert] = \alpha^2
$$
By measuring the system you're observing the qubit not as it was but as it collapses.

So to summerize:

-- classical uncertainty comes from ignorance
-- quantum uncertainty comes from the quantum nature of the reality

This is why there are different types of information theory in general. But entanglement, which is a quantum phenomena plays a role to.

a pair of entangled quantum systems are in general correlated, the information is not stored in one or two of the system but in the correlation between them. And by measuring one, one gains information about the two of them. This is a really simple view for this but I hope it's enough.

Answer (score 1):

**The main differences**

A modern perspective is that quantum information theory is a generalization of classical probability, so the latter is a strict subset of the former. There are two key differences:

1. Classical probabilities $p_i$ range from zero to one, and satisfy $\sum_i p_i = 1$. Quantum probabilities $\psi_i$ are [complex numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number), and instead satisfy $\sum_i |\psi_i|^2=1$.
2. Whereas classical probabilities represent ignorance about distinct, independent configurations/states of something, quantum probabilities can interact with each other via interference (or more precisely unitary evolution, which is necessarily linear). A classic illustration of interference is the [double slit experiment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment).

**The details**

There are way too many difference to enumerate or explain here, but I'll mention a few important ones. None of the following are true in classical probability theory, but all hold in quantum information theory:

- Measurement of quantum probability distributions leads to a loss of information, as measurement collapses a complex wave function into a classical probability distribution via the [Born Rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule) $p_i=|\psi_i|^2$. This is referred to as wavefunction collapse.
- [No-cloning theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-cloning_theorem) says that unknown quantum states cannot be copied (this is a non-trivial consequence of 2).
- Quantum states exhibit types of correlations that do not occur classically. This is called [quantum entanglement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement). For example, imagine the joint probability distribution over the states of two distinct objects (e.g. two bits). Classically, if the entropy of object A, marginalized over (i.e ignoring) object B, is non-zero, then the entropy of the joint distribution must also be non-zero. However quantum mechanically, it is possible for the marginal distribution to have non-zero entropy but the joint distribution to have zero entropy.* A classic example of this is the Bell state on two qubits $|00\rangle + |11\rangle$. This state and many others violate [Bell's inequalities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem).

Classical and quantum probabilities are given a unified description via the [density matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix). There are tons more exotic features of quantum information theory. It's not very intuitive at first, but it's a fascinating subject!

*A fun way I have heard this explained is that a classical house is at least as messy as it's messiest room, but a Quantum house can be messy in every room but clean when you consider it as a whole.